# Converting triangle angles into navigation bearing

Tags: c#, math, gps, coordinates

## Background Information

I am trying to extrapolate GPS coordinates throughout a network mesh of radios. The radios I am working with have an API function that returns the Time of Flight data between the radio called on and the radios it has had communication with. Using this Time of Flight data, I calculate the distance between two different radios. Using the distance between radios and the known GPS coordinates of a single "primary" radio, I create a sequence of SSS triangles and calculate the angles on the triangle using the law of cosines. Now I need to convert the angles in the triangle into navigational bearing from the primary radio. From there I can calculate GPS using an equation I found [Here (Formula to find a lat lon point, when bearing, distance and another lat lon is given)](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/).

### Question

How can I convert angles in a triangle to navigational bearing (0 being true north)?

Is this even possible?

### Attempted

I was looking at calculating the slope / gradient [(source)](https://sciencing.com/convert-angle-degrees-slope-8128171.html)

but from what I am reading I need a coordinate system to translate slope to bearing, which I do not have.

Comment: Angle start from positive x = 0 degrees and go around a circle counter-clockwise (which is east).  So North is then 90 degrees.  So adding 90 degrees goes from angle to navigational bearing.

Comment: @jdweng...is this really just a case of overthinking it? I was thinking I had account for angles that would end up in different quadrants and some how relate that back cardinal directions. Math has always been my Achilles heel so I can believe I am making this  bigger than it has to be, but it just seems to easy to be true.

Comment: @jdweng also, if all the angles in a triangle add up to 180 it would be impossible to get a bearing value higher than 270? which leaves about 90degress of possible direction unaccounted for? sorry if I am missing something basic here, just doesnt seem to add up to me

Comment: Yes.  North was used for zero degrees because that is where the North Star is located.  when we are on earth we always used east as zero degrees where the sun rises.  So it is  the difference between night and day.

Comment: What would the angle be for NE?  North = 0, East = 270, North-East = 315

Comment: @jdweng thats what I am confused on. If NE is 315, I can not get that value if I am simply adding 90degress to the triangle angle. Since the 3 angles in a triangle add up to 180, the highest angle value I can get is 179.98..adding 90 to that would get me approx. 270 which is east...so I could never get NE as a value?

Comment: Do not think of it as a triangle.  You have two points on opposites corners of a rectangle where the top/bottom edges are latitudes and left/right are longitudes.  Then draw a diagonal across the rectangle between two points.

Comment: @jdwent thanks for the information, I will hopefully get to test this out fully sometime soon. if you want to post this as an answer I will gladly accept it

Comment: Here is something to think about.  I live 18 miles from the Empire State Building 350 feet above sea level.  The floors of the Empire State Building are 10 feet.  So when I look straight out at the building I should see the 35th floor but instead I see the 53rd floor.